# Gnome desktop stuck on login when recover from sleepmode

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, login

Environment:Ubuntu 18.04LTS on my laptop,with i5-8265U,worked normally before.
I has faced this issue 2 weeks before,actally.I went into the login screen,typing the password,and it just after a splash(with blank screen with purple),returned into the login screen---**and then my keyboard and touchpad and mouse don't work at all**.I had to make an force reboot by pressing the POWER botton.**And after the reboot,the kryboard and touchpad worked well.**
I know I had asked some similiar questions before.But it is differernt from this.Last problem was when you completing some tasks,such as gaming,and the Desktop environment got frozen.It is because the Xwayland crashes and system cannot restart it.  **however,after that I used Xorg along with gnome**.And this time the bug is different because you can see the transition animation but you cannot do anything becauses your input is not working(keyboard,etc)
I went into /var/crash and there is nothing .here is the *syslog* in /var/log. hope it will help.

```
Jun  6 22:42:49 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
Jun  6 22:42:49 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jun  6 22:42:49 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jun  6 22:42:49 machrev-S1-Pro systemd-sleep[13108]: Suspending system...
Jun  6 22:42:49 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [21110.110299] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd-modules-load[383]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd-modules-load[383]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd-modules-load[383]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.3.0-56-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-017) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #50~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 27 08:52:12 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-56.50~18.04.1-generic 5.3.18)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-56-generic root=UUID=41226dd2-7d76-4c72-9b6c-5cf05c49dc48 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
```

…

and here are I fond some errors>(I don't understand what these means)

```
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.372766] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-327)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.372771] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.372773] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.381003] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-327)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.381008] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Starting Modem Manager...
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.381010] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.383748] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-327)
Jun  6 23:17:44 machrev-S1-Pro kernel: [    0.383753] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221)
```

does anybody can give me some advice?Really thanks.